# Tex not work: I use Google Chrome as the browser .....

Tags: support, mathjax

I have not faced up this problem before. But today, when I open the website, I can just see the code, not the formula. Besides that, opening the website is far more slower than before.

Comment: Where are you physically based? It is possible that there's some problem loading MathJax due to connectivity problems.

Comment: @ Willie Wong I can open other websites fast

Comment: Yes, but your location may have problems accessing the content distribution network used by StackExchange and or MathJax. Without giving more information, and unless other users can confirm that they too are seeing this problem, your much-too-brief description of the problem will likely be closed and marked as non-reproducible.

Comment: Obligatory: Have you tried [Ctrl+Shift+R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache#Google_Chrome)?

Comment: @Willie Wong but I don't have this problem when opening MAthoverflow

Comment: @Rahul Narain it doesn't work

Comment: @gingerjin: which actually affirms my assertion. Math.SE loads MathJaX from `cdn.mathjax.org`, while MO runs their version from their local server `latex.mathoverflow.net`. That MO works has pretty much 0 relevance to your problem. A better test would be to see if you can see the math display on http://stats.stackexchange.com or http://physics.stackexchange.com ; or see if you can get http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/ to render correctly.

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/latex-is-not-properly-displayed  It has been rumoured that the Chinese web censorship system blocks MathJax. If you live in a region where there's government mandated web access control, *that* may be the issue.

Comment: If you use Firefox, one thing you can do to help clarify the issue is to open up "Tools -> Web Developer -> Web Console" and try to load http://math.stackexchange.com. That should show you why MathJax is failing to load and why you are, if I guessed correctly, getting connection timed-out issues which slows down your browsing. There are probably similar tools for Opera and Chrome. If you specify your operating system and web browser someone can help you find the appropriate tool to identify the problem.